# How do I install the Xray mod for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I am wondering how to download the
[X-ray mod.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/867079-164-xray-mod/&ei=wRWSUoWYHrOtsAT824GwBg&usg=AFQjCNFJaWCvf2bQpau8H_cMGvmklGyNDA&sig2=SO2rBSdmETzhRpAxu547JA&bvm=bv.56988011,d.cWc)

I have Forge installed (version 1.6.4) and I downloaded the 1.6.4 version of the X-Ray mod and placed it in the mods folder of the .minecraft directory. But when I login, it only shows the other mods that i downloaded. It does not show the x-ray mod.

The mods that i downloaded are:

- Minecraft Coder Pack
- Forge Mod Loader
- Minecraft Forge
- Player API
- Pixelmon
- Smart Moving
- Smart Render

So, is it another mod that interferes with it?

Comment: Don't hack bro :P

Comment: XD. No, I don't plan to use the mod to hack. Just to see how it affects gameplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with this for a while (just for fun though(dont use it on a server(It's still unfair compared to the other players))). I used a x-ray texturepack which you can just put in your texturepack in .minecraft or directly through minecraft itself.

StrongestCraft : http://resourcepack.net/category/x-ray-resource-packs/

I hope this helped.

**Edit**

Since this is a texture-pack and no mod it doesn't interfere with any mods. The obvious downside it that you cant combine this with a fancy hd texture pack but you wouldn't see any blocks anyhow so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, was either looking for an alternative to "download" the mod. I just wanted to see how it can affect gameplay. Thanks a lot, Marco Geertsma.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a YouTube link for the install,

and here is the thread on Minecraft Forums http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/867079-164-xray-mod/

Comment: Whilst these links answer the question, it's better to summarise the content here, and use the links as references only, to prevent link rot.